# Cant initialize spring-boot Database

Tags: spring, database, spring-boot, maven

When I download the `database navigator` and try to enable it, it is required that I restart `IntelliJ IDEA`, but when I restart `IntelliJ IDEA`, it shows me this problem.

> Plugin 'DBN' failed to initialize and will be disabled.  Please
>   restart IntelliJ IDEA.

```
com.intellij.openapi.extensions.impl.PicoPluginExtensionInitializationException: Duplicate registration for EP: com.intellij.methodImplementor: original plugin com.intellij, new plugin DBN
    at com.intellij.openapi.extensions.impl.ExtensionsAreaImpl.checkThatPointNotDuplicated(ExtensionsAreaImpl.java:284)
    at com.intellij.openapi.extensions.impl.ExtensionsAreaImpl.registerExtensionPoint(ExtensionsAreaImpl.java:289)
    at com.intellij.openapi.extensions.impl.ExtensionsAreaImpl.registerExtensionPoint(ExtensionsAreaImpl.java:128)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.IdeaPluginDescriptorImpl.registerExtensionPoints(IdeaPluginDescriptorImpl.java:392)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManagerCore.registerExtensionPointsAndExtensions(PluginManagerCore.java:1548)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManagerCore.initializePlugins(PluginManagerCore.java:1453)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManagerCore.initPlugins(PluginManagerCore.java:1586)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManagerCore.getLoadedPlugins(PluginManagerCore.java:139)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.getComponentConfigs(ComponentManagerImpl.java:291)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.init(ComponentManagerImpl.java:79)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.load(ApplicationImpl.java:407)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.load(ApplicationImpl.java:393)
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:208)
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.lambda$initApplication$0(IdeaApplication.java:74)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:764)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:734)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:347)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe plugin version isn't compatible with the Intellij version, try to remove plugin manually from a plugins directory and later check those versions on provider site.

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519